# Ignore meta key when inputting unicode on OSX

Tags: key-bindings, osx, unicode

I'm a newbie running emacs 26.3 (9.0) on OSX in the graphical mode (i.e. **not** in the terminal) and am writing a document with Devanagari (sanskrit text).

Some of the letters in the inbuilt devanagari keyboard can only be input with a combination of the meta key and another letter. For e.g. `META i` prints `इ`

However, emacs interprets the `META + <somekey>` and claims that it is an invalid command. Is there a way to disable the meta-key feature of emacs, even temporarily, so as to input the characters that I want? If this isn't possible, how can I input characters that require the `META` key?

[image: Error displayed in emacs]

Comment: Depending on which emacs for mac you're using you may have `ns-option-modifier` and `ns-right-option-modifier` (or `mac-option-modifier`, `mac-right-option-modifier`) variables you can modify. If you set one of these to `'none` it should let you enter the Denanagari text. I have my option modifier set normally but right-option set to none so that I can use the right option key for those characters. Try `M-x` `customize-group` `ns` and look for "Alternate Modifier".

Comment: There's a 'devanagari' emacs input method as well, that would be independent from any OS-level input method.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I added a macro to my .emacs file such that the left alt/option key is ignored by emacs and the alt/option key on the right continues to work.